# Implementing callback in extendable button class

Tags: java, android, extends

I have a very simple 'CustomButton' class which extends the default 'Button' class. My CustomButton uses onTouchEvent and I want to pass down a function from my Activity to the CustomButton and get it executed on touch down.

The CustomButton class is working fine, but I can't seem to figure out how to pass down a function to it.

Activity:

```
public class mainActivity extends Activity
{
    @Override
    public void onCreate( Bundle savedInstanceState )
    {
        super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );

        Context context = getApplicationContext();
        setContentView( R.layout.main );

        LinearLayout root = (LinearLayout) findViewById( R.id.myLayout   );   
        View child1 = getLayoutInflater().inflate( R.layout.child, null );

        // Define the button
        final CustomButtom myCustomButton = (CustomButtom)child1.findViewById( R.id.button_id );   

        myCustomButtom.setCallback( test ); // <-- I want to pass my 'test' function to CustomButton class, 
                                            //     so it can get executed by the onTouchEvent

        root.addView( myCustomButton );

        super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );
    }

    private int test()
    {
        Log.d( "test", "Callback executed!" );
    }
}
```

And this is my CustomButton class:

```
public class CustomButtom extends Button
{
    private Function callback;

    public CustomButtom(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);

        this.setOnTouchListener
        (
            new OnTouchListener() 
            {
                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) 
                {
                    if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) 
                    {
                        executeCallback(); // <-- My callback would get executed from here
                    } 

                    return true;
                }
            }
        );

    }

    public void setCallback(Function function)
    {
         callbackFunction = function; // Save the callback in a local variable
    }

    private boolean executeCallback()
    {
        return callbackFunction.execute(); // execute the callback
    }
}
```

Is there a 'data type' such as 'Function' which I can use for this purpose or is there different way how to accomplish this? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You usually need an object and a function when you want to perform an action in Java. This is what Interfaces are for. You declare an interface with the name of your function. Your Activity implements this interface and the function and then you pass to the button the instance of your activity. In your case you are probably looking for OnTouchListener or OnClickListener? If you want to have a special interface, you can declare it the same way.

```
public class mainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener
{
    @Override
    public void onCreate( Bundle savedInstanceState )
    {
        super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );

        // I do not see any reason to use the Application Context here. Your Activity has the right context for your UI
        // Context context = getApplicationContext();
        setContentView( R.layout.main );

        LinearLayout root = (LinearLayout) findViewById( R.id.myLayout   );   
        View child1 = getLayoutInflater().inflate( R.layout.child, null );

        // Define the button
        final CustomButtom myCustomButton = (CustomButtom)child1.findViewById( R.id.button_id );   

        myCustomButtom.setOnClickListener(this);

        root.addView( myCustomButton );

        // you did this already
        //super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );
    }

    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        Log.d( "test", "Callback executed!" );
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**

to keep the logic inside the button you can create your own interface (OnClickListener is an interface) like this:

```
public interface OnCustomActionListener {
    // you can remove the button as parameter if you do not care which button the action came from 
    void onCustomAction(CustomButton button);
}

public class CustomButtom extends Button {
    OnCustomActionListener onCustomActionListener;

    public void setOnCustomActionListener(OnCustomActionListener listener) {
        this.onCustomActionListener = listener;
    }

    /* Creator like in your question mentioned */

    private boolean executeCallback() {
        if (this.onCustomActionListener != null) {
            this.onCustomActionListener.onCustomAction(this);
        }
    }
}
```

in your Activity:

```
public class mainActivity extends Activity implements OnCustomActionListener {
...
     myCustomButtom.setOnCustomActionListener(this);
...
public void onCustomAction(CustomButton button) {
     // do something
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The problem is that I have also custom 'longpress' and animation related events which trigger at odd times (which are inside the CustomButton class). If I could pass down the function CustomButton, then I could trigger it at these odd times. Using this approach I would have to move or copy the logic from CustomButton to Activity->onClick event (if I understood correctly). Can you please tell me how can I do this via 'passing down' the function, rather than catching the buttons onClick/onTouch events inside the activity? or is this approach illogical? Thanks!

Comment: For example when inside ButtonClass->onTouchEvent is triggered, if user holds down the button for 3500ms, then it should execute one callback, if user holds the button and slides to the right, it should trigger another callback. It would be very efficient development wise, if I could simply tell my CustomButton class which functions to trigger from the main activity on which events, then I would have all the event logic inside the CustomButton class and it would trigger these callbacks once the animation is complete for example.

Comment: If the logic of CustomButton is related to the button and maybe even used several times, it is logical to keep that logic inside the button and create a new Interface (OnClickListener is an interface) that has one defined function that is executed in your activity. I have modified my answer